# Mercurial `hg clone` but ignoring all subrepos?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to clone a repo that comes with subrepos, but without having Mercurial pull all the subrepos?

It appears that while `hg clone -U` can be used to obtain an empty clone of a repo, there's nothing that would convince `hg update` to avoid starting off by pulling all of the subrepos.

I should point out that it is crucial to retain the ability to easily sync to the head revision after creating such a clone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer may add more than the question required, but provides some valuable notes on working with Mercurial when you can't update do to a bad subrepository path or revision.

Step 1: Clone the repository without any updates

```
hg clone --noupdate source_repository destination_repository
```

Step 2: Use revert to get the right files

```
hg revert --all --rev revision_number --exclude subrepo_1 --exclude subrepo_2 ...
```

At this point, you have a new changeset; you may need to make sure the parent revision is correct. When I did this, my new changeset's parent was changeset 0. To fix this I had to set the parent changeset AND switch branches (since my changeset was on a different branch).

Step 3: Change the parent of the current changes

```
hg debugsetparents revision_number
hg branch branch_name
```

That should do it.

Comment: After Step 3, `hg status` still shows all the files as pending adds. Running `hg debugrebuildstate -r tip` fixes that.

Answer (score 14):

This should do what you want:

```
REM Take a new clone, but do not update working directory
hg clone --noupdate %REPO_PATH% %DESTINATION%

REM Update working directory but exclude the certain subprojects
hg revert --all --rev %BRANCH% --exclude %SUBREPO_PATH_1% --exclude %SUBREPO_PATH_2%
```

Answer (score 5):

Found a hacky way. It still requires all subrepos to be checked out once, but afterwards they can be deleted.

1. Clone the whole lot, including subrepos. No way around this.
2. Delete subrepos
3. `hg remove .hgsub`

I tried to convince Mercurial to `hg remove .hgsub` before the subrepos are cloned, but the best I got is `not removing .hgsub: file is untracked`.

Comment: This solution really doesn't help if your external subrepo is inaccessible for some reason. Some discussion about ignoring subrepos [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2520).

Comment: @MattJoiner What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a subrepo, a working directory **must** include some version of that subrepo.  That version may be a fixed older revision if specified, or the tip if not.

You cannot update your repo without getting the subrepos; if you had a complete working dir without them, you shouldn't be using subrepos - use truly external repos instead.

If your subrepos are pegged against a certain remote version, then updates after the first will not trigger a subrepo update - they're already up-to-date.  But for the initial creation of the working directory, you will have to do a remote pull.

You can trick Mercurial by munging the `hgsubstate` file.  But really, your model and the conceptual model differ, so you're probably not a good match for subrepos if this is a concern.

edit: If you find yourself cloning and then updating to the tip many times, try using local branches or `mq` instead.  That way you only have to do the initial clone once.

Comment: They seem a good match most of the time. It's just that the subrepos are large, and the best way to diff against the official "server" that I found is to keep a clean local checkout. The subrepos add a ton of overhead to this approach.

Comment: @romkyns: if you're just looking to keep track of what you've changed, use `hg out` (or `hg diff` for uncommitted changes).  Or you could just create the "clean" clone once, and use `hg pull -u` on it occasionally to keep it up to date...

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just have to tolerate a bunch of extra copies of these huge subrepos. I find `hg diff` suboptimal for reviewing code and use external GUI-based diff instead.

Comment: romkyns: `hg diff` will use your external diff viewer if you set it up right.  Also, do take a look at `hg mq`.  Really.  Quilt is a nice program.