# How to make local clone without pulling subrepos again?

Tags: mercurial, clone, dvcs, subrepos

I often work with Mercurial by keeping a local store of my upstream clones, and then just cloning again locally for my actual working environment:

```
$ cd /clones
$ hg clone ssh://external-repo.example.com/some/repo/path/foo
$ cd ~/Development
$ hg clone /clones/foo
```

This is particularly useful for me because I often want to make new clones on airplanes, etc., where I have no internet access.  However, this doesn't work when the original clone contains subrepos - the presence of the `.hgsubstate` file means that `hg` will always go out to the internet instead of grabbing the local cloned revision (even if they are the *same*).  Is there any way to make a local clone copy the files without going out to the internet?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436549/mercurial-hg-clone-but-ignoring-all-subrepos) has an answer which would probably work, but seems very unfortunate for long-term management (deleting the `.hgsubstate` file in the clone in `/clones/`, and then making local clones from that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "trivial" subrepository path in your `.hgsub` file like this:

```
foo = foo
bar = bar
```

This is the [recommended setup](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository#Recommendations). The advantage of setup a layout is that a clone has the **same structure** as the repository you clone from. You can thus clone your clones when on a plane.

Alternatively, you can use the [`[subpaths]`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#subpaths) setting to re-map the URLs to local paths. This lets you add

```
[subpaths]
http://server/(.*) = /clones/libs/\1
```

to your `~/.hgrc` file and then you'll see that paths are remapped to `/clones/libs` when you clone.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want - probably too hard to change all our existing repos to "trivial", but will use that for new ones.  Thankfully, subpaths will solve my problem for existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by cloning the subrepositories yourself. Supposing that foo has a single subrepo called bar:

```
$ cd ~/Development
$ hg clone -U /clones/foo
$ hg clone -U /clones/foo/bar foo/bar
$ hg update -R foo
```

The update does not need to access the internet since the subrepository exists and contains the necessary changeset for the update on the master.